# SQL / PDO Query Optimisation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Still getting my head around SQL.

At the moment I am using 2 PDO Queries. The scope of what I am trying to do is as follows:
- First I need to convert a `name` to a table `ID`
- Then using this ID, get the people whose `companyID` match the retrieved table `ID`

So currently I have: (PS I know there are PDO shorthands, i'm just not using them in this project atm for consistency across all the php scripts)

```
$prep = $DBH->prepare("SELECT Company.id FROM Company WHERE Company.name = :companyName LIMIT 1");
$prep->bindParam(":companyName", $_GET['companyName']);
$prep->execute();
$data = $prep->fetch();
$companyID = $data['id'];

$prep = $DBH->prepare("SELECT People.* FROM People WHERE People.companyID = :companyID");
$prep->bindParam(":companyID",$companyID);
$prep->execute();
```

I'm under the impression that I would be able to use some sort of `JOIN` - probably an `INNER JOIN` to be able to do this in a single query.

Is this possible? - If yes, an example would be very much appreciated!

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is SQL 102.

You need this query:

```
 SELECT People.* 
   FROM Company 
   JOIN People ON People.companyID = Company.id
  WHERE Company.name = :companyName
  ORDER BY People.Surname, People.Givename
```

I am guessing at the column names in the `ORDER BY` clause. But this will yield all the people associated with `:companyName` in a single query.  This is efficient. SQL's made for this.

Comment: Sorry, but just to clarify.. The WHERE statement must always be on the outer most 'parenthesis level' even if say there were more than one join? (Hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular bias of mine, but I like using a sub-select. This should work:

```sql
SELECT People.* FROM People 
  WHERE People.companyID  IN 
     (SELECT Company.id FROM Company WHERE Company.name = :companyName LIMIT 1)
```

But this could also work:

```sql
-- Aliasing is optional
SELECT P.* FROM People AS P
  JOIN Company C ON (P.companyID = c.id)
  WHERE C.name = :companyName
```